# Prolog read compound term and treating it like an expression

Tags: prolog, logic, swi-prolog, gnu-prolog

The following code isn't working

```
:- arithmetic_function(i/2).

i(X,Y,Z) :-
         Z is X+Y.


calcola :-
        write('Give me an expression'),nl,
        read(ESP),
        Z is ESP,nl,nl,
        write(Z).
```

but the following is

```
:- arithmetic_function(i/2).

i(X,Y,Z) :-
         Z is X+Y.


calcola :-
        write('Give me an expression'),nl,
        Z is 4 i 2,nl,nl,
        write(Z).
```

Why is that? Seems like the "read" function isn't working properly

Comment: What do you mean by 'isn't working' ?

Answer (score 3):

from SWI-Prolog mailing list ([SWIPL] Ann: SWI-Prolog 5.11.23, 23 Jun):

- MODIFIED: User-defined arithmetic functions have been removed from
  the kernel.  There is a new library(arithmetic) that emulates the
  old behaviour PARTIALLY.  Notably:

  - This library must be loaded before arithmetic_function/1 is
    used.
  - It only covers arithmetic functions that are visible as an argument
    to is/2, >/2, etc. at compile-time.
  - A new predicate arithmetic_expression_value/2 can be used to
    evaluate expressions with embedded user arithmetic that become
    instantiated at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Well as a lead, when I test it with `is/2` it fails but when I use `arithmetic_expression_value/2` it succeeds :

```
:- arithmetic_function(i/2).

:- op(20, xfx, i).

i(X, Y, Z) :-
    Z is X + Y.

calcola :-
    writeln('Give me an expression'),
    read(ESP),
    arithmetic_expression_value(ESP, Z), nl,
    write(Z).
```

For @gusbro, it works out of the box. I'm using windows swi-pl here, for the record !

Others may have clues about why it fails for us !

Comment: I successfully run OP code using is/2. **?- calcola.
 Give me an expression
|: 4 i 2.


6**

Comment: That's strange. I am using SWI 5.10.4. I guess you are using GNU Prolog ? (In fact, i don't see arithmetic_expression_value/2 in SWI)

Comment: nah as I precised in my edit i'm on swi too (5.10.5, windows)

Comment: swipl 5.10.1, debian here, the original doesn't work, modified version works. Shouldn't i be defined as an operator anyway? if I write 'i(4,2)' OP code works fine. @gusbro http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=arithmetic:arithmetic_expression_value/2 (maybe it was added in 5.10.5)

Comment: @thanosQR: Yes, you have to define it as an operator. I assumed OP forgot to put it because otherwise his second program would be invalid. In my SWI 5.10.4 i get **Undefined procedure: arithmetic_expression_value/2** with Mog's code

Comment: I remember a notice of SWI-Prolog mailing list about the change of arithmentic_function recently. Maybe some flag reenable it. Going to search...